# flvmux not pulling video at same rate as audio

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspberry-pi3, gstreamer-1.0

I have a pipeline which is intended to capture audio and video from a C920 camera, do a little very simple processing on it (low cpu requirements), then recompress it and mux it to file.

This is a general outline of the pipeline:

```
Platform:
- Raspberry Pi 3
- Debian Jessie
- GStreamer 1.8
```

[image: Bad Pipeline]

Don't worry about my 'simple processing' area. My overall CPU sits below 25% CPU.

What I find, is that Q3 and Q4 slowly start filling up, until one hits a threshold and then my audio goes all choppy (and I get warnings from alsasrc 'downstreaming is not consuming buffers fast enough').
I can put leaks on the queues, but that's hardly resolving the issue.

As my pipeline is running, this is what my queues look like (current-level-time in ms)

```
QUEUE CONTENTS IN MILLISECONDS

TIME(s)     Q1     Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
      0      0      0     0     0     0     0
      5      0      0   252   380     0     0
     10      0      0   293   460     0     0
     15      0      0   332   470     0     0
     20      0      0   378   451     0     0
     25      0      0   333   460     0     0
     30      0      0   383   480     0     0
     35      0      0   500   550     0     0
     40      0      0   500   610     0     0
     45      0      0   539   630     0     0
     50      0      0   584   670     0     0
```

=== EXPERIMENT ===

I removed the *yellow* leg of the pipeline, so that I was only capturing video, and the result was better. I had no queues which just kept 'growing' - and the output video was perfect.

```
QUEUE CONTENTS IN MILLISECONDS

TIME(s)     Q1     Q2    Q3    Q4    Q5    Q6
      0      0      0     0     0     0     0
      5      0      0     2     0     0     0
     10      0      0     5     0     0     0
     15      0      0     8     0     0     0
     20      0      0     8     0     0     0
     25      0      0     8     0     0     0
     30      0      0     8     0     0     0
     35      0      0     8     0     0     0
     40      0      0     8     0     0     0
     45      0      0     8     0     0     0
     50      0      0     8     0     0     0
```

Also, I tried the following pipeline (I have omitted the queues from the diagram), with complete success - video recorded for at least 10 minutes with no issues.

[image: Good Pipeline]

=== THE QUESTION ===

What is going on?

My guess is that because Q3 (the video output) is filling up, then the audio must be slowing things down.
Because Q4 is filling up, and NOT Q5 - that must mean that alsa is producing audio more quickly than the aac encoder can compress it - is that correct?
However, my CPU usage is very low - I've tried with 2 aac encoders (voaacenc, and avenc_aac), and an MP3 encoder, all with the same issue.

======== UPDATE =========

I've put a couple of identity elements after the audio, and video (directly after), and charted the PTS of their outputs. You can see that they very quickly start drifting away from each other. By the time the video is at 30s, the audio is well behind at 21 seconds.
Here is a chart

[image: A/V drift]

======== UPDATE 2 =========

I had a second camera, and swapped that over, and the problem went away. The audio and video PTS values stayed in sync for at least 25 minutes.
The difference with this new camera - is it's a modified C920, with a custom lens fitted. The lens coincidentally happened to be pulled completely out of focus - and that is what fixed the PTS drift (if I focus the custom lens, I get the same PTS drift).

So - the question has changed a little: Why does an in-focus C920 camera drift its PTS so badly?
Note: I am turning off auto-exposure, and setting the exposure-absolute value to the default of 250.
I would prefer to be able to use the auto-exposure however...

Comment: Possibly related? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=165002

Comment: Does you processing do anything with the timestamps?

Comment: Also: Does you processing have an `appsink`? Is there any logs about the latency calculation if you crank up the `GST_DEBUG` variable?

Comment: @Velkan no I don't do anything with the timestamps... no appsink....

Comment: @Velkan I'll check the latency asap - I've just spent the last day trying to upgrade to 1.10.4 to pick up the fix mentioned here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=165002 unfortunately the result was an even more broken implementation that produced totally corrupt h264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have resolved the issue. For anybody reading :)

If you are using a Raspberry Pi, even a v3 - ensure you have configured `peak-bitrate` to no more than `3650000` (3.65Mbps) on your `uvch264src`. I am also capturing audio at 24khz - if you're not doing that you might be able to eek out a little more.

If you set it to more, or omit it entirely, you will experience the same odd issues I had. Movement and high-detail in the video footage will cause the encoded H264 to outrun what the Pi can handle. So your issues will be odd and sporadic.

I can only think that the C920 is saturating the USB bus - odd, because USB2 is supposed to be good up to 480Mbps - and the limit I've set is 3.65Mbps.
I have heard that the Raspberry has a very flawed USB firmware blob - but had never encountered it, until now.

Problem solved. I have been considering moving to a dragonboard... this might have given me the best reason yet.